# When I send file, the response returns empty object in React

Tags: reactjs, request, formik, dropzone, sendfile

I have a problem with sending files in React. So, I have a big form. All data send, but files send empty object, not binary files. I use Formik and Dropzone.

Result

[image]

Some part of Formik and request. `Jsondata` is that some of the values need to change json format and `fileData` is my files.

```
      <Formik
          initialValues={{
            name: "",
            ...
            file: null,
            note: "",
          }}
          // validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={async (values) => {
            const jsonData = {
              ...values,
              address: JSON.stringify(values.address),
              products: JSON.stringify(values.products),
            };
            console.log(values.file[0]);

            let fileData = new FormData();
            fileData.append("file", values.file[0]);

            await axios.post("https://nehra.az/api/add-supplier", { jsonData, fileData });
          }}
```

Parent component

```
   <div className="form-input">
                  <Dropzone setFieldValue={setFieldValue} />
                  <span className="error-span">
                    <ErrorMessage name="file" />
                  </span>{" "}
                </div>
```

Child component (Dropzone)

```
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isFocused, isDragAccept, isDragReject, acceptedFiles } = useDropzone({
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => props.setFieldValue("file", acceptedFiles),
  });

  const files = acceptedFiles.map((file) => <li key={file.path}>{file.path}</li>);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({ style })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} multiple />
        <p> Click to download the file or drag the file here.</p>
        {files ?? <ul>{files}</ul>}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```